# Take pairs from a list in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

I gathered the files that end with `PST.shp` and `DBOUND.shp` accordingly. Then saved to the lists as the code shows.

the list `ps`

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\sa\\43001\\PST\\PST.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\sa\\43003\\PST\\PST.shp']
```

and `db`

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\sa\\43001\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\sa\\43003\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp']
```

Later, should be in a loop that uses the first pair in each list and do operations.Then the second pair and so on:

Like this:

```
for i in list(zip(ps,db)):
    db1 = gpd.read_file(db[0])
    pst1 = gpd.read_file(ps[0])
    db1['geometry'] = dbound.buffer(0.001)
    wdp = gpd.sjoin(pst1, db1, how="left", op='within')
```

The question is how to do this without setting [0] and so on each time but do it automatically for all the existing pairs in each iteration?

**Update**

During export each export replaces the previous in the loop how to export them each in a folder that will have the name of the original folder like this:
for the if the dir is 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\43001\PST\PST.shp` make a folder named 43001 and have the exported file and the same for the rest; here is my code for the export.

```
    o = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\resultss'
    out = o+'\\'+'pst'
    wdp.to_file(out)
```

Comment: You never use the zipped list you create, db1 and pst1 are i[1] and i[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `zip`.

**Ex:**

```
for i, v in zip(ps,db):
    db1 = gpd.read_file(v)
    pst1 = gpd.read_file(i)
    db1['geometry'] = dbound.buffer(0.001)
    wdp = gpd.sjoin(pst1, db1, how="left", op='within')
```

Comment: it was a typo. Do you know why you don't put list like `list(zip(ps,db))`?

Comment: Because `zip` is a `iterator`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: The exported file gets replaced in every iteration. See the update in the question to understand.Can you help with that part? Thank you